# Chrome Extention: sending data from background.js to contentscript.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

im trying some stuff with chrome exstion API, and i want to send a data from the background.js to the contentscrip.js .  everything i did fails, even tried the copy and paste the google example, and still no go. (doing this for 2 days lol)

here is my json file:

```
    {
  "name": "BlaExtension",
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "bla the the exstion",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs","http://*/*","https://*/*"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
       "matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
      "js": ["content_script.js"]
    }
  ],

     "permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://www.google.com/*"
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function (tab) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { greeting: "hello" }, function (response) {
        alert(foo);
    });
});
```

content_script.js

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  alert(request.greeting);


});
```

i tried looking for help in old posts on messaging here on stackoverflow but nothing seem to help. 
what im doing worng?
(sorry for my english)

Comment: `chrome.tabs.getSelected` is only executed once, when your extension is loaded. Obviously, your content script was not activated at that time. As a result, there's no handler for the sent message.

Comment: oh,didnt know that. can u give me an exmple to how to fix this?

Comment: What do you want? I can't make anything senseful from your application, because its design is far from logical atm.

Comment: i just want simple explntion or a code expmle on how should i do this. if that ok.

Comment: THat's ok, but you have to define "how should i do ***this***". What are you trying to achieve? Sure, you want to develop a Chrome extension, and pass a message between the background and a content script. As I explained in my first comment, the latter works fine. Now, where are you stuck?

Comment: i want to how have the abiilty to to send data from the background to the content script so i can fill out form when the page finish loading . in the end when i understand how it will work i want to add a popup page with some text box's so i can have an input to the data i want to fill in the form(name password). (i hope u understand me :P )

Comment: So, you want to get information from the background, and use it to autofill an input field? What is the trigger? As I said, the code in the question works in theory, but it has to be wrapped in a useful event listener/function.

Comment: i want to understand how to send messages the correct way in the extention. so i can get input and use it with the injected script.

Comment: So, to get it straight: Input in browser action popup -> Extension magic -> ??? -> Populate fields in a tab? Edit your question to clarify this if that's true.

Comment: yes but i want info only about the messaging accros the extention for now. so i can expriement with that a litell. im trying to understand piece by piece and add them togther. ( i realy want to understand what im doing)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13416/discussion-between-rob-w-and-samy)